# Notification not triggering when view controller updated on Navigation stack changed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send a notification on changing the navigation stack update. But it's not triggered. Here is my code. I have a requirement to change the root view controller on button action.  I'm trying the below code, but it's not working for me.

```
import UIKit


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func replaceThirdViewControllerAsNavigationRoot() {
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        nc.post(name: Notification.Name("Notify"), object: nil)
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [ThirdViewController.instance()]
    }
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userLoggedIn), name: Notification.Name("Notify"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func userLoggedIn() {
        print("-----")
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    static func instance<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
        let name = String(describing: self)

        guard let controller = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name) as? T else {
            fatalError("ViewController '\(name)' is not of the expected class \(T.self).")
        }
        return controller

    }

}

extension UIStoryboard {
    static var main: UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of event is wrong. When you post a notification, you need to make sure that an observer already exists, otherwise the notification will be discarded.

In other words: make sure that

```
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userLoggedIn), name: Notification.Name("Notify"), object: nil)
```

runs **before**

```
nc.post(name: Notification.Name("Notify"), object: nil)
```

Comment: nc.post(name: Notification.Name("Notify"), object: nil)
Posting this from SecondViewController. Then added observer in ThirdViewController.

Comment: Which, like I said, is the wrong order. Observers _must_ exist before `post` can do anything meaningful.